# Printing sublists of list with odd length haskell programming

Tags: haskell

I want to print sublists of list having odd length. i coded this.

```
sublists :: [a] -> [[a]]
sublists [] = [[]]
sublists (x:xs) = if odd (length (tail xs))
                  then [x:sublist | sublist <- sublists xs] ++ sublists xs 
                  else sublists xs
```

eg: `sublists [1,2,3,4,5,6]`

I am getting output as :

`[[1,3,5],[1,3],[1,5],[1],[3,5],[3],[5],[]]`

I want :

`[[1,3,5],[2,3,4],[2,3,5],[1],[2,3,6],[3],[5],[2],[4],[6],[1,2,3],[1,2,4],[1,2,5],[1,2,6],[1,3,4],[1,3,6],[1,4,5],[1,4,6],[1,5,6],[2,4,5],[2,4,6],[2,5,6],[3,4,5],[3,4,6],[3,5,6],[4,5,6],[]]`

Comment: Why don't you want subsequences of length 5?

Comment: Start with `oddSublists = filter oddlength . allSublists`, then write `oddlength :: [a] -> Bool` and `allSublists :: [a] -> [[a]]`.

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd reuse [`subsequences`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:subsequences) until I was pretty sure this was the bottleneck. Especially since you seem comfortable calling `length` a lot, it seems like efficiency isn't a big concern. So:

```
Data.List> filter (odd . length) . subsequences $ [1..4]
[[1],[2],[3],[1,2,3],[4],[1,2,4],[1,3,4],[2,3,4]]
```